# Should the “a” in “poco a/à poco” be accented in the original Italian?

Tags: notation, terminology

This one’s mostly for language nerds:

I usually see “poco a poco” spelled without an accent on the “a”, but now and again I see it spelled “poco *à* poco” – it’s written that way in some scores, and [Googling “poco à poco” (with quotes)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22poco%20%C3%A0%20poco%22) turns up a lot of results with that spelling, so it doesn’t seem to be that uncommon.

So my question is for anyone who isn’t just familiar with Italian music terms, but who’s actually fluent in the language and understands its grammar and spelling rules: Is the “a” in “poco a poco” accented in the original Italian? And if not, why do some people spell it that way?

Comment: Good question and I am looking forward to the answer.  One possible explanation is hypercorrection.  People think: it's foreign so it must look weird.  Another possibility is confusion with French.  Note I am just guessing which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is correct that there should be no accent on *a*. However it was common practice, up until the 1700s (before the modern Italian orthography was developed later on) to use accents more liberally, even in Italian territory.

Apart from *poco à poco*, you also find *ricercar à 6*, and similar instances concerning the number of voices, or even *à diminuire* (synonymous to *diminuendo*). All of these *a*’s would not be accented nowadays. Another old Italian allography is *leggiero* and derivatives, which today would be spelled without the *i*.

Comment: Note that the spelling _à_ was [common](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XZhPC1Y-SOUC&pg=PA189) before the standardisation of Italian for modern _ha_, the third person singular pres. indic. of _avere_ (to have). Likewise, _ò_ = _ho_, _ànno_ = _hanno_.

Comment: This is quite certainly the preposition we’re talking about

Comment: I suspect this arises due to a conflation of Italian notation and French notation by people who speak neither language.

Answer (score 2):

There is no accent on the word "a" in Italian. The only use of à is to mark a change of pronunciation if it is the final letter of a word.

"Poco à poco" is presumably an error following the logic that "foreign languages have accents". I have also seen things like "D.C al finé" written by people who presumably don't know that the final e in "fine" is pronounced anyway!

Comment: could it be that this means that the *à* must be separated from the *o* of poc*o* and not tied to *oa*.?

Answer (score 0):

poco a poco: Italian

French: peu à peu.

poco à poco: Spanish? wrong!

> Is the “a” in “poco a poco” accented in the original Italian?

like you say: the music language is Italian and there is no accent.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poco_a_poco

> And if not, why do some people spell it that way?

Because they don't know better ;) probably derived from the French peu à peu.

[link](https://books.google.ch/books?id=-ON_W1ubAmoC&pg=PT238&lpg=PT238&dq=%22poco%20a%20poco%22%20o%20%22poco%20%C3%A0%20poco%22&source=bl&ots=342TqGyjeG&sig=ACfU3U12HK-dsXM9o6R3MTu-K0HjYjlo9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhgJL4tuXnAhVhxKYKHcohCZIQ6AEwB3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22poco%20a%20poco%22%20o%20%22poco%20%C3%A0%20poco%22&f=false)

Edit: Spanish is poco a poco (tambien!)

I can't say where this **à** comes from... may be this means that the **à** must be properly separated from the **o** of poc**o** and shouldn't be  tied to **oa**.?